# C multi-loop for() basics

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

How to write example code without goto and without additional procedure call?

```
for(i=0;i<imax;i++)
{   for(j=0;j<jmax(i);j++)
    {   for(c=0;c<cmax(j);c++)
        {   if(!check1(c))
            {    if(check2()) goto ni;
                 else goto nj;
            }
        }
    // **EDIT** procedure call is here
nj:;
    }
ni:;
}
```

Comment: use `break` instead of `goto`  ?

Comment: State Machine design? implement states on every loop and check to use continue(s) and/or break(s)

Comment: make all of the conditionals in the nested loops false (according to the number you want to break out of), then break from the inner-most loop. You have no code after the check here, but be advised any code after this in "parent" loops would execute one more time before breaking.

Comment: btw there is nothing inherently wrong with goto, it just leads to extremly messy code in most cases, but you dont have to write messy code just to avoid `goto`

Comment: Breaking out of nested loops is one of the remaining cases where `goto` is the cleanest solution.

Comment: The `goto nj` is simply a `break`.

Comment: @joelw and under the hood a `break` is simply a `goto` ;)

Comment: @tobi303 Absolutely, but if you are trying to break out of the innermost loop, `break` is clearer.

Comment: @joelw he doesnt want to break out of the innermost loop only, but conditionally also out of some of the outer ones. Imho the original code is much clearer than the accepted answer (nevertheless I think it is a good answer to the question, given that `goto` is not wanted).

Comment: @tobi303, you right, goto in this case is most simply and clean solution. I don't like break in multiple loops from old compilers, where sometimes break breaks over two for()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code:

```
    bool flag = false;
    for(i=0;i<imax;i++)
    {   for(j=0;j<jmax(i);j++)
        {   for(c=0;c<cmax(j);c++)
            {   if(!check1(c))
                {    if(check2()) {flag=true;break;}// goes to ni
                     else break; //goes to nj
                }
            }
            if(flag){flag=false; break;}
            nj:;
        }
        // procedure
    ni:;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`goto nj` can be replaced with `break`. however, `break` can't help you if you need to break out of nested loops. I think this is a perfectly legit use case for `goto`. The only alternative I can think of is to sett the loop counter outside of its range, e.g. `c = cmax(j)`. Worse than `goto`, in my opinion.

Comment: I dont really agree that "break cant help". He could use a flag to kind of forward the break to the outer loops. Whether this would be better than `goto` is a different question.

Comment: I don't quite agree with respect to "break can't help", or "break can help". Perhaps it's also a matter of wording and pragmatism. I dare say  I've seen examples of good programming practice using `goto` for breaking out of multiple nested loops and it is perhaps one of two scenarios I'm also using a `goto` in C. Although I understand this does not answer the question, using a `break` whenever one can achieve the goal without overtaxing the code by declaring, setting, checking against and resetting additional variables, flags, etc. is the best solution.